Weird crash catched in AppDelegate on Catalyst / Sonoma when dismissing a UIViewController
On Catalyst / Sonoma using .modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen is causing a weird crash on AppDelegate 0x000000
Use .modalPresentationStyle = .automatic instead.

Please don't post answer within a question. Post answer separately.
